# How do I overcome Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1827: restore failed...exceed licensed limit?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm attempting to extract data from a SQL Server backup provided by vendors with whom we no longer work.

I only need data from some tables, but I need to examine the database structure to determine exactly what I need.

This is the only use I have for SQL Server and I don't what to buy in big.

I tried SQL Server Express to restore the .bak file locally and received the error:

> Restore failed...
>   CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 4096 MB per database.
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1827)

I am having difficulty determining what alternative approach or minimum license I need to purchase to get me past this database size limit. The database seems to be only marginally over the limit.

I used `RESTORE FILELISTONLY`, `HEADERONLY` and `LABELONLY` commands to extract what metadata I could.

> HEADERONLY
>   BackupSize:  4958099456

I'm running SQL Server Express 2008 on a Win XP 32 bit platform, which could be part of my problem.

The version I'm running:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (Intel X86)  
Sep 22 2011 00:28:06  
Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  
Express Edition on Windows NT 5.1 <X86> (Build 2600: Service Pack 3)
```

Can anyone tell me the least expensive and most efficient way out of this problem?

Thanks,
Neale

Comment: this should be on DBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server [2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26727) or [2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx) Express have a 10GB limit so you can use one of those.